# Correcting time for daylight savings in rails DateTime.parse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, timezone

Just adding to the million questions about time zone and DST issues out there.

I have a form with separate date and time fields that I combine to create a DateTime like so

```
start_time = DateTime.parse("#{parse_date(form_date)} #{form_start_time} #{Time.zone}")
```

If I fill out my form with 21 Aug 2012 and 15:00, then these are the values that I see when I reload my form. If I then look at my start_time attribute in my model it is correctly set to `Tue, 21 Aug 2012 15:00:00 EST +10:00`.

The problem I am having occurs if I use a date later this year once daylight savings kicks in (I am in Australia). If I use 21 Dec 2012 and 15:00 then check start_time I see `Fri, 21 Dec 2012 16:00:00 EST +11:00`.

My interpretation of the problem is that the date is being saved in my current time zone (+10:00) as this is what I have told DateTime.parse to do. However when the value is returned, Rails is looking at the date and saying 'hey, it's daylight savings time in December' and returning the time in the +11:00 time zone.

What I want to do is tell DateTime.parse to save the time in the +11:00 time zone if DST is in effect. Clearly passing Time.zone into my string doesn't achieve this. Is there a simple way of doing this? I can see ways of doing it using Time#dst? but I suspect that this is going to create some really ugly convoluted code. I thought there might be a built in way that I'm missing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's my solution so far. I'm hoping someone has a better one.

```
start_time = DateTime.parse "#{date} #{(form_start_time || start_time)} #{Time.zone}"
start_time = start_time - 1.hour if start_time.dst? && !Time.now.dst?
start_time = start_time + 1.hour if Time.now.dst? && start_time.dst?
```

It seems to work but I haven't rigorously tested it. I suspect it could be prettied up and shortened but I think this is readable and understandable. Any improvements?

Comment: shouldn't this be if Time.now.dst? && !start_time.dst?

Comment: @brad, I realize this is a really old question, but did you ever settle on a better way of handling this? If not, did you find that this worked well? Thanks!

Comment: How would rails know dts is on?  It's different in different time zones, and even different geographies.

Answer (score 25):

(Answer for Rails 4.2.4, didn't check for older or newer versions)

Instead of using fixed shift +01:00, +02:00, etc, I recommend to use the `in_time_zone` String method with time zone name as argument :

Summer time :

```
ruby :001 > "2016-07-02 00:00:00".in_time_zone('Paris')
 => Sat, 02 Jul 2016 00:00:00 CEST +02:00
```

Winter time :

```
ruby :002 > "2016-11-02 00:00:00".in_time_zone('Paris')
 => Wed, 02 Nov 2016 00:00:00 CET +01:00
```

`String#in_time_zone` is the equivalent of :

```
ruby :003 > Time.find_zone!("Paris").parse("2016-07-02 00:00:00")
 => Sat, 02 Jul 2016 00:00:00 CEST +02:00 

ruby :004 > Time.find_zone!("Paris").parse("2016-11-02 00:00:00")
 => Wed, 02 Nov 2016 00:00:00 CET +01:00
```

You can get the time zone names by :

```
$ rake time:zones:all
```

Or in rails console :

```
ruby :001 > ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.map(&:name)
```

Or build collection for select tag :

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.map do |timezone|
  formatted_offset = Time.now.in_time_zone(timezone.name).formatted_offset
  [ "(GMT#{formatted_offset}) #{timezone.name}", timezone.name ]
end
```

And store the time zone name instead of the shift.

**Note** : don't confuse `String#in_time_zone` method and the `Time#in_time_zone` method.

consider the time zone for my system is 'Paris'.

```
ruby :001 > Time.parse("2016-07-02 00:00:00")
 => 2016-07-02 00:00:00 +0200 
ruby :002 > Time.parse("2016-07-02 00:00:00").in_time_zone("Nuku'alofa")
 => Sat, 02 Jul 2016 11:00:00 TOT +13:00
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this exact issue. My app allows users to see upcoming events. In the US we fall of DST on November 2nd and all events on and after that date were showing times an hour early.

We require the opportunity to have the timezone selected and stored to its own field. Before I was using the following to store my datetime:

```
timezone_offset = Time.now.in_time_zone(params[:opportunity][:time_zone]).strftime("%z") #-0700
DateTime.parse("#{params[:opportunity][:start_datetime]} #{timezone_offset}")
```

To fix the issue I have changed to:

```
start_datetime = Time.zone.parse(params[:opportunity][:start_datetime])
```

To display the correct times we use:

```
@opportunity.start_datetime.in_time_zone(@opportunity.time_zone)
```

Answer (score 1):

With Rails, we can use ActiveSupport::TimeZone for this:

```
tz = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
tz.parse(date_str_without_zone).to_datetime
```

I use [TZip](https://github.com/farski/TZip) to get TimeZone strings (e.g. "Pacific Time (US & Canada)") from zip codes.

Answer (score 0):

I wouuld try and use

```
Australian Eastern Standard Time (AEST) (UTC +10).  
Australian Central Standard Time (ACST) (UTC +9 ½).  
Australian Western Standard Time (AWST) (UTC +8).
```

which adjust for Daylight Savings.

Comment: How and where would I set those. I don't see those time zones listed when I do rake time:zones:all

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a custom date/time format, different than the supported by `String#in_time_zone`, you could also use (since rails 5) [`strptime`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-i-parse) like:

```
Time.find_zone!('Auckland').strptime('2021-02-02 08.00.00', '%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S')
```