# How can I convert a Time from some timezone to UTC, taking into account Daylight Saving, in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, timezone

I have an app where different users are in different parts of the globe (I know their timezone), and they can enter dates and times, and I need to store everything in UTC on the DB.

Normally to instance my Time variable, I'm doing:

```
DateTime.new(date.year, date.month, date.day, hours, minutes, 0)
```

This is already in UTC, but without converting.

If I add a 7th parameter to that string with the time_zone (ie. "Melbourne"), then it will interpret it as a a date in Australia, and the resulting DateTime, when converted to UTC, is 10-ish hours behind, and that works.

However, that's not taking into account Daylight Saving.

What I need is to do exactly that (instance a DateTime from the components of a date/time), such that (in the case of Australia, for example), using the same hours/minutes for April 9th will give me a different offset when converted to UTC than if I used April 5th.

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Daniel

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056264/correcting-time-for-daylight-savings-in-rails-datetime-parse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [`tzinfo`](https://github.com/jedverity/tzinfo)

```
irb(main):002:0> require 'tzinfo'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> tz = TZInfo::Timezone.get("Australia/Melbourne")
=> #<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Australia/Melbourne>

irb(main):004:0> tz.utc_to_local(Time.parse("2013-04-05 00:00:00"))
=> Fri Apr 05 11:00:00 UTC 2013
irb(main):005:0> tz.utc_to_local(Time.parse("2013-04-09 00:00:00"))
=> Tue Apr 09 10:00:00 UTC 2013

irb(main):015:0> tz.local_to_utc(Time.parse("2013-04-09 00:00:00"))
=> Mon Apr 08 14:00:00 UTC 2013
irb(main):016:0> tz.local_to_utc(Time.parse("2013-04-05 00:00:00"))
=> Thu Apr 04 13:00:00 UTC 2013
```