# Rails time in the past in a given timezone - not in utc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, time

Let's consider the following date: `4 dec, 2017 10:00AM`

`DateTime.parse("4 dec, 2017 10:00AM")` returns the time in UTC. 
I would like to get the `DateTime` in the timezone `"Asia/Beirut"` where the time is `10:00AM`

The problem is that the UTC timezone differs between now ( `UTC+3` ) and December ( `UTC + 2` ).

In brief, given `4 dec, 2017 10:00AM` , I would like to get a `DateTime` with the value: `4 dec, 2017 10:00AM UTC+2`

Is there any method that I have missed in the documentation?

**EDIT**
Here's how this looks in Javascript

```
new Date(2017, 10, 12)
Sun Nov 12 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET)
new Date(2017, 9, 12)
Thu Oct 12 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (EEST)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Time with zone and parse the date in that time

```
Time.zone = 'Asia/Beirut'
Time.zone.parse("4 dec, 2017 10:00AM")

Mon, 04 Dec 2017 10:00:00 EET +02:00
```

Comment: Interesting way ( + 1 ) - not sure about the threading implications though of `Time.zone`

Answer (score 0):

The answer comes in the `String` class
and as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/41001934/226255

`"4 dec, 2017 10:00AM".in_time_zone("Asia/Beirut")`

returns what I'm looking for

`Mon, 04 Dec 2017 10:00:00 EET +02:00`